# ./startup.sh: command not found error

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu

I downloaded `tomcat9` zip file and extracted all files. now I am running

```
/bin$ sudo ./startup.sh
```

i am getting this error

```
sudo: ./startup.sh: command not found
```

all files are there then why this error ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

you need to make the file executable.
run `chmod +x startup.sh` and then `sudo ./startup.sh`

Comment: If you are trying to run this on mac os, give permission to catalina.sh

Answer (score 8):

On Mac OS:

If you do not have Apache Tomcat installed go to https://tomcat.apache.org and download the tar.gz from the "Core:" list.
Extract the contents:

```
tar -xf <filename>.tar.gz
```

Rename the resulting directory to: CATALINA_HOME and run the following commands:

```
cd CAATALIN_HOME/bin
+x startup.sh
./startup.sh
```

*When prompted: enter your Mac OS password*

```
chmod +x catalina.sh
sudo ./startup.sh
```

Tomcat started.

Answer (score 4):

[Tomcat Running in Mac OS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlsd5.png)

For Mac-OS , you should take ./catalina.sh file to run Tomcat

Please see the image above in a link

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod 755 ./startup.sh

bash ./startup.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`export PATH=/where_the_path/tomcat/bin:$PATH`

it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

go to the bin folder.run bellow two commands

```
chmod 777 startup.sh
chmod 777 catalina.sh
```

to start tomcat

```
sudo startup.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to change the permission for your file :

- chmod +x startup.sh

then :

- sudo ./startup.sh